# NSWindow: Passing mouse events through window to whatever is underneath

Tags: cocoa, macos, mouseevent, nswindow

Is it possible to pass mouse events through an `NSWindow` to whatever is behind it (even if it is a window from another application)?

I am using `NSWindow` to create a desktop overlay, but would like to still be able to interact with other windows, even if they are behind my overlay window.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

IIRC, you can just use `[window setIgnoresMouseEvents:YES]`.

Comment: This solution renders the overlay window (even non-transparent parts) unusable.

Comment: @tofutim: Yes, that is what was requested here — to pass mouse events through the overlay (e.g. the way the volume overlay works).

Comment: Chuck, do you happen to know how I can just pass the click-through events through the transparent areas? It doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: @tofutim: NSWindow normally uses its drawn content as a mask and passes clicks through transparent regions. You might want to post a question about your situation if it doesn't seem to be working right.